# Sensitivity of a matrix rank to objective function in semidefinite optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-rank, semidefinite-programming

I have a question regarding the effect of an objective function on getting rank-1 solution for semidefinite optimization. I'm trying to minimize the following objective function

> Minimize $ c_0\ (\Re[Tr(A_1W)] + \Re[ \ Tr(A_2W)]) + [1 - Tr(EW)]^2 $

When I choose $c_0 \leq 1$. 
I could not get rank-1 solution (have more than 1 positive eigenvalue of $W$, which is positive semi-definite matrix). Could anyone explain to me what is the importance of choosing proper $c_0$ in my objective function?

Thanks,

Comment: I presume you are minimizing with respect to W and constraining W to be hermitian semidefinite, but you didn't explicitly tell us that. At minimum, you need to provide us with the complete formulation of your optimization problem. Can you provide a minimally-sized reproducible problem, complete with input data and results, which is sufficient to illustrate the phenomenon you've observed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. I'm wondering if it is possible to sent my code to your email, so you can have a look at my problem?

Comment: You should post what you can here.